# Pandas dataframe - change output formatting Jupyter for groupby()

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

[image]

I would like to change my table above from the categorical values: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] to the values they represent for presentation/display purposes: ['Asian', 'Black', 'Hispanic', 'White', 'Unknown/Other'].

In addition, I would like to change the name of the ACTIVITY_DATE column to just COUNT.

How do I do those two things in the most simple/direct manner?

Thanks in advance to a great community!

Comment: Please include a reproducible input that can be copy pasted along with excepted output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first task,

```
df_gp = df_gp.replace({'DRIVER_RACE': {1: 'Asian', 2: 'Black', 3: 'Hispanic', 4: 'White', 5: 'Unknown/Other'}})
```

To rename a column,

```
df_gp.rename(columns={'ACTIVITY_DATE': 'COUNT'}, inplace=True)
```

To rename the index column,

```
df_gp.index.name = 'COUNT'
```

Comment: Thanks for that - the column rename works for me no issues, but the .replace() seems to fail. I think maybe because it's an index?

Comment: By "fail" I mean, just doesn't change. I don't get any errors.

Comment: Yes. I updated the answer with renaming the dataframe index

Comment: Yes, how about to change the values of the index - e.g. change 1 to 'Asian', 2 to 'Black', etc.

Comment: You could try something like df_gp = df_gp.rename(index={1: 'Asian', 2: 'Black'})

Comment: Please do accept the answer if it answers your question